# Configure different email backends in Pyramid .ini file

Tags: python, pyramid

I'm developing a reasonably basic app in [Pyramid](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/index.html). The app includes functionality to send email. Currently I'm intending to use Sendgrid for this purpose but do not want to couple it too tightly. Additionally, I do not want any emails sent out during development or testing. My solution is to create lightweight middleware classes for each provider, all providing a `send()` method.

I imagine loose coupling can be achieved by using the [`Configurator`](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/config.html#pyramid.config.Configurator) object but I'm not quite there yet.

If given the following code (note there is no `request` as I want to be able to call this via [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/)):

```
def send_email(sender, recipient, subject, contents):
    emailer = get_emailer()
    emailer.send(from=sender, to=receipient, subject=subject, body=contents)
```

How would the `get_emailer()` function look like, assuming my development.ini contained something like `pyramid.includes = my_app.DumpToConsoleEmailer`?

Answer (score 1):

Your mention of Celery changes everything... Celery doesn't make it very obvious, but a Celery worker is a completely absolutely separate process, which knows absolutely nothing about your Pyramid application and potentially runs on a different machine, executing tasks hours after your web application created them - a worker just takes tasks one by one from the queue and executes them. There's no request, no Configurator, no WSGI stack, no PasteDeploy which assembles your application from an `.ini` file.

Point is - a Celery worker does not know if your Pyramid process was started in development or production configuration, unless you tell it explicitly. It is even possible to have a worker executing tasks from two applications, one running in development mode, and another in production :)

One option is to pass the configuration to your celery worker explicitly on startup (say, by declaring some variable in celeryconfig.py). Then a worker would always use the same mailer for all tasks.

Another option is to pass a "mailer_type" parameter explicitly from your Pyramid app to the worker for each task:

```
@task
def send_email(sender, recipient, subject, contents, mailer_type='dummy'):
    emailer = get_emailer(mailer_type)
    emailer.send(from=sender, to=receipient, subject=subject, body=contents)
```

In your Pyramid app, you can put any key/value pairs in your `.ini` file and access them via `request.registry.settings`:

```
send_email.delay(..., request.registry.settings['mailer_type'])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have not marked it as accepted though as it  suggests using `Request` for getting the registry settings.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't totally clear: the last code example is called from the Pyramid process, where you do indeed have access to request. From there, you explicitly pass some variable to the `send_email` task (by calling send_email.delay(...)), so that when it's executed in the worker process it can determine which mailer to use.

Comment: @Sergey I am in the same problem right now. What did you do for this problem ?

Comment: How is this the accepted answer? It does not state how to implement the `get_emailer` function?

Comment: @shredding: The answer goes to great length to illustrate how to modify the existing get_emailer() function so it can use different email backends, by passing it a parameter from the Pyramid process. From the question it looks like the OP already has the function, which always uses the same backend - modifying the function is a matter of adding a few if/else statements. The concrete implementation if the `get_emailer` function depends on the  actual mailer used (the OP was going to use Sendgrid), and is largely irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Since asking the question a month ago I have done a bit of reading. It has lead me to two possible solutions:

### A) Idiomatic Pyramid

We want to address two problems:

1. How to set up a class, specified in a PasteDeploy Configuration File (.ini file) globally for the Pyramid app
2. How to access our class at runtime without "going through" request

To set up the specified class we should define an `includeme()` function in our module and then specify the module in our .ini file as part of `pyramid.includes`. In our `includeme()` function we then use `config.registry.registerUtility()`, a part of the [Zope Component Architecture](http://muthukadan.net/docs/zca.html), to register our class and an [interface](http://muthukadan.net/docs/zca.html#interfaces) it implements.

To access our class at runtime we then need to call `registry.queryUtility()`, having gotten the `registry` from `pyramid.threadlocal.get_current_registry()`.

This solution is a bit of a hack since it uses `threadlocal` to get the config.

### B) Lazy Module Globals

My personal solution to the problem was more simple (and likely not thread-safe):

```
# In module MailerHolder:
class Holder(object):
    mailer = None

holder = Holder()

def get_emailer():
    return holder.mailer

#In module ConsoleMailer:
import MailHolder

class ConsoleMailer(object):
    def send(self, **kwargs):
    # Code to print email to console

def includeme(config):
    MailHolder.holder.mailer = ConsoleMailer()
```

Comment: I can't see how either solution would work in the worker process. How is `includeme()` is getting called in the worker process and where is that `config` parameter it receives come from?